# change both image and text css properties simultaneously with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have some images and corresponding images names. I want to change both image and corresponding image name (css properties) simultaneously in some time interval (fadeIn/fadeOut for images).
My html code:

```
<div id="s_links">
<ul class="s_list">
    <li class="home_p"><a class="lists1">img1 name</a></li>
    <li class="home_p"><a class="lists2">img2 name</a></li>
    <li class="home_p"><a class="lists3">img3 name</a></li>
    <li class="home_p"><a class="lists4">img4 name</a></li>
    <li class="home_p"><a class="lists5">img5 name!</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="slideshow">
   <img  class="one" src="img1">
   <img  class="two" src="img2">
   <img  class="three" src="img3">
   <img  class="four" src="img4">
   <img  class="five" src="img5">
</div>
```

for example if current image is 'img3' , then css should be :-

```
jQuery(".lists3").css({
    "background-color": "#677FC6",
    "border": "1px solid #677FC6",
    "border-radius": "6px"
});
jQuery(".lists1,.lists2, .lists4,.lists5").css({
    "background": "none",
    "border": "none",
    "color": "#000"
});
```

Please Help me... Thankz

i tried with this codes, images working perfectly but css cant change

```
$(function() {
    var current = 0;
$imgs = jQuery('#header .abc71');
    imgAmount = $imgs.length;
    $($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();
    window.setInterval(swapImages, 4000);

    function swapImages() {
        var $currentImg = $($imgs[current]);
        if(current == imgAmount-1) current = -1;
        var $nextImg = $($imgs[++current]),
            speed = 1500;
        // animation speed should be the same for both images so we have a smooth change
        $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
        $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please show ,what you have tried ?

Comment: Please edit your comment into the question. No one likes to read minified code :)

Comment: Try: `imgs.css({'color': 'white'})`

Comment: sorry, questions updated... :)

Comment: @Raffael  i already tried that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UYHDc/3/)

```
function swapImages() {
  var $currentImg = $($imgs[current]);
  if(current == imgAmount-1) current = -1;
   var $nextImg = $($imgs[++current]),
    speed = 1500;
   // animation speed should be the same for both images so we have a smooth change
   $currentImg.fadeOut(speed);
   $nextImg.fadeIn(speed);
   $("[class^=lists]").css({"background":"none","border":"none","color":"#000"});
   $(".lists" + ($nextImg.index()+1)).css({"background-color":"#677FC6","border":"1px solid #677FC6","border-radius":"6px"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following :

- create a function that you will trigger on a regular basis using setTimeout
- in this function, you will have an integer variable that you will represent the index of the current image
- your function will fadeOut the current image and update its name's CSS properties (your current code does not show that)
- this variable will be incremented at every call of the function (or set to zero if too high)
- your function will then fadeIn the new current image and update its name's CSS properties (your current code does not show that either)
- end of your function

Comment: i dont want to fade out image names, all image names must list near to the slide show, i want to highlight image names with some css

Comment: Looks like you know what the function should be doing but you're having trouble with the CSS properties update. Please show the code portion you've been using to do that so you can get some help understanding what is wrong.